# How to Detect when ios app really close

Tags: ios, signals, sigkill

I'm developing an application for iOS and i need to be able to detect when an app really closes and not when he go to background..

I already try to catch the signal SIGKILL with signal function but signal handler never has been called.. I'm using push notifications and i have to register the device in the server for the server send notifications to him when application starts (and that its possible) but i have to unregister the device when the device quit the application and not when the device have the application in background..What i can do for doing this?

Regards

Comment: have you tried it with `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` in appDelegate already? :)

Comment: Yes i've tried that and the applicationWillTerminate isnt called because this application is running only in multitasking devices and due to the apple documentation in multitask devices this callback isnt called in all exit situations. What i can do more?

Comment: if the app isn't closed by a normal close command but by a kill command, it will be hard to tell apple's sandbox that you want to handle this interrupt now ^^

Comment: Why do you need to unregister for Push Notifications when the app closes? One of the primary uses of Push Notifications is to provide communication to the user when the app is not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OS kills your app for any reason, it is killed. There is no notification. You can't catch the SIGKILL signal. Look at the man page for `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting when app closes in all the cases is not reliable in iOS (nor it is in other OS). By design, you should avoid it.

Change your design and do not unregister the token from the server. In Apple Push Notification service, the app token is still valid after app is closed and you may use it to deliver a push notification when the app is not running.